# How to find or search the content in google sheet using C#

Tags: c#, google-sheets-api

I need to search some data in google sheet's column 1 and update the values in column 2 and column 3 in matching row using C# code.
I tried using the Data Filter API, but didn't succeed.

Can you please suggest another API to use?

I tried Data Filter and Conditional Formatting class provided by Google SpreadSheetResource class.

Search value is=2 in column 1 and update 24/08/2019 in column 2 in matching row

```
              column1  column2      column3
                2         21/08/2019   user1
```

Expected Output:

```
              column1  column2      column3
                2        24/08/2019   user2
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like that have an API for "searching" or "filtering" based on text.  I think your best bet would be to download the entire spreadsheet as a CSV through the Drive API.  Then load it into a DB or memory and filter it from there.

If you need this kind of thing done across large documents, or a large number of documents, maybe there is a way to sync the whole list down separately, and then have a process that looks through the files.

This is the closest thing I could find:

The reference page in the API documentation for [Data Filter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DataFilter).  I'm guessing that you'll need to use that with the method [getByDataFilter](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter).  If you take a look at the [examples](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/getByDataFilter#examples) they don't really show you how to actually filter... just how to make the call.  But unless the `a1Range` property in `DataFilter` is what you need, I think you're out of luck for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at: GetByDataFilter(GetSpreadsheetByDataFilterRequest, String)

https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/latest/api/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsResource.html